# Put webMathematica folder outside Tomcat webapps folder?

Tags: webmathematica

Is it possible to put the `webMathematica` folder outside the usual Tomcat `webapps` folder and still have web*Mathematica* work?

web*Mathematica* does work OK if its whole folder is placed inside Tomcat's `webapps` — and accessed in the browser as `localhost:8080/webMathematica`.

(This is with Tomcat 9 under OS X 10.10.4 and using web*Mathematica* 3.3.2 calling *Mathematica* 10.2.)

Configuration details would be greatly appreciated!

In asking this I have four aims:

1. Granularize things so that I can just back up the `webMathematica` folder, along with other documents of mine, separately from backing up Tomcat's own files such as those in its distributed `webapps` folder.
2. Be able to access web*Mathematica* (and, eventually, some specific apps using it) on localhost by means of a simple URL "alias", such as `webmathematica`, rather than the usual complete URL `localhost:8080/webMathematica` — just as I can now access Tomcat's webapps by entering the URL `tomcat.local`.
3. [added] Still allow use of Tomcat for webapps other than web*Mathematica*. Thus changing the entire Tomcat `docBase` value — if that actually worked — would *not* allow achieving this aim.
4. [added] Be able to run web*Mathematica* in my browser by entering a simple URL such as `webmathematica.local`(without the fully-qualified URL `localhost:8080/webMathematica`).

Comment: Did you try a symbolic link?

Comment: @Rolf Mertig: Yes, a symlink works, with URL `http://localhost:8080/webMathematica`! But what I'd actually like to do is use a simpler URL such as `webmathematica.local`, and for that obviously some kind of additional configuration of tomcat and/or apache is required. (In apache I'm passing calls to tomcat via ajp.)

Comment: For the URL part I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5132959/1159366) and no.4 in [this](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html) should get you started...

Comment: Alas, I don't comprehend how to put the "this" and "no. 4 in this" together for the situation I describe. Don't I need, also to add an entry such as `127.0.0.1  webmathematica.local`  to `/etc/hosts` and a corresponding `VirtualHost` entry to `apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`?`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. So you don't have to type the `webMathematica` after your localhost address.

Steps:

1. Put your webMathematica folder in some place like C:\webMathematica
2. Create a file named ROOT.xml inside `\Tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\`
3. In this file, write: `<Context docBase="C:\webMathematica" reloadable="false"/>`
4. Restart you Tomcat, and now your new root is your webMathematica application

Comment: Will test this with my OS X configuration & report back soon. Thanks!

Comment: @murray let me know if it works

Comment: No, that's not working (OS X 10.10.4) even if I keep the `webmathematica` folder in its default position `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps` and use that location in the `docBase` value in the file ` /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml` that you describe. After restarting Tomcat (and apache), browsing to localhost:8080 still brings up the default Tomcat page, not the webMathematica page.